# Draw a 2d space-time diagram in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am very new to tikz. I was wondering if someone could tell me how to go about drawing a space-time diagram pretty much like the one included below within latex. Thank you[image]

Comment: I'd suggest starting with a MWE.

Comment: The read the TikZ manual.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! See these instructions for creating a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). However, if you are new to LaTeX, I recommend creating the diagram in the image software of your choice and then including the image you create in your document with the `graphicx` package. You don't want to tangle with TiKZ, in my opinion, while simultaneously trying to get to grips with the basics of LaTeX. The latter is quite enough to be doing at one time!

Comment: Please provide your starting code and tell us, what the specific problem is. For now, I will put the question on hold, to not encourage draw-all-for-me-questions. It can be reopened when improved and clarified.

Comment: Yes sorry I will edit the question a soon as I have time. Thank you.